# How do I add a chi-square test to a crosstab() function

Tags: r, statistics

The code I am using is:

```
crosstab(variable1, variable2, weight, plot = F, digits = 1, expected = T, prop.c=T, prop.r=T)
```

In my class example, the crosstab includes a chi-squared test. I assume there was a mistake in the code I am given, so what do I do to the `crosstab` code above so that it also returns a chisquare test below the table?

Also, is there a way to include phi in this table so I don't have to manually calculate phi each time?

Comment: `crosstab` is not in base installation of R, so you'll have to figure out which package was used in your class. Also, it would be nice if you included what package you're using in your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know. I'm using car and descr

Comment: -1 for failing to read the help page (which had the answer) before posting.

Answer (score 3):

I googled for `cran descr` and opened up the [reference file for the package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/descr/descr.pdf). I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and found where `crosstab` is located. I read the argument names and found that there is an argument called `chisq = FALSE` and the description for it says

> If TRUE, the results of a chi-square test will be printed after the table.

Comment: Ya, sorry. I just started using R this week and am not familiar with the online resources. Everyone, I'm sorry for asking such a basic question

Comment: @Hutchins you can get the same document by typing `?crosstab`.